# How to programically add a component?

Tags: java, android

i have android app and need to add adding controls with for each cycle programmatically. Now i have hardcoded 20 items and deleting which is unused on entire for each cycle. I have `cardview` and in `cardview` 5 `textview`, 1 `imageview` and `color`. Wanna ask, how to add it programmatically with correct `constrains` into my app. Or is it possible to create my own control to palette and add it after that?

Thanks a lot for help.

I tried code programmatically adding component, i can add simple buttons etc, but i have `CardView` with more components in this `cardview` and have problem how to add it and make Constrains.

Answer (score 0):

Already done and working. Thread can be closed.